# Is there a way to setup two users with one account?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I purchased Ubuntu One and was wondering if there was a way to share the 20GB storage with another user on the same computer.  Something like a family plan, with shared storage but separate files, synced to different `/home` directories.  It seems to me if I don't need all 20GB it would be wasteful to pay twice.

Comment: This is possible with symlinks, though tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just set Ubuntu One to sync the same U1 account to each system account?  Both users will download the files from the Internet (rather than just getting copied to their home directory), but this seems to me to be the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  Both ideas probably work in my situation.  While the remote access and sync feature between different computers are nice to have; I'm most interested in remote back-up of important files, i.e. photos and music in case of failure.  It seems that most back-up regimes approach this as if every user should purchase individual solutions.  In a multi-user computer world I thought maybe U1 might have approached this differently.  Family A with users 1,2,3,... and purchase additional storage as needed.  I guess for now I'll have to purchase U1 for my wife.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not set Ubuntu One to sync the /home directory in it's entirety, and set it to not sync various sub folders that you don't want synced?

Answer (score 0):

You couldnot put anything in ~/Ubuntu One, and use instead two UDFs. So your wife can sync ~/wife and you sync ~/husband